# is it possible to pass values to an access report from both vba and from a form?

Tags: ms-access, parameters, vba

I have a set of reports than currently run from a 'Select Report' form.  Users select the report name and the start and/or end dates they want to view, and the query underlying the chosen report looks at the controls on the form to filter the report to the selected dates.

We now want to automatically run some of these reports every Monday morning, to send out via email.  The start and end dates for the reports will be Date() and Date()+14.  I know how to code to run the report and attach it to email, but I can't work out how to programmatically pass dates to the form's underlying query, instead of it looking to the form controls.

I've searched for the answer but can only find answers explaining how to do one or the other, but not if it's possible to do both using the same report. 
I've tried to use parameters in the report's underlying query instead, but then I get prompt boxes for the date paramaters when I open the report from the form, even though dates have been selected on the form and are passed through to the report as expected.

I've also tried to pass the dates via openargs instead of looking directly to the form controls, but then I can't work out how to pass those openarg values into the query, only to controls on the report.  That means the displayed start and end dates are correct, but the date filtering isn't applying to the report.  From stepping through it, the report loads the data before the OnLoad code runs which sets the controls to the openargs values, so they are null at the point the data is filtered.

Any help is much appreciated, I'm a bit stumped on the best approach from here. Thanks.

Comment: Setting the date criteria of the query to `Date()` and `DateAdd("y", 14, Date())` perhaps?

Comment: @KostasK.  So do you mean don't try to pass just the dates to the existing source, supply the whole record source with the amended criteria?  I'd not thought of that option, thank you.  However, it's a large number of reports, so the coding to supply the amended record source for each of the possible reports means it would probably be easier just to duplicate the reports and have one set that works with the form, and one that has parameters to work with the auto generation/email process. I was hoping to find a way to solve this without duplicating the reports.

Comment: No, I mean the report's underlying query. Instead of passing the dates as parameters to the query, let the query figured them out. That is of course if you need the report dates to always default to today and today +14.

Comment: Something like `SELECT * FROM T WHERE [Field] BETWEEN Date() And DateAdd("y", 14, Date());`

Comment: thanks @KostasK.  Unfortunately the dates are only today and today + 14 when we run them for email on a Monday morning.  When users run the report from the current selection form they can select any start or end date, or leave one or both dates blank.

Answer (score 0):

I have reached a working solution for this, it may not be the most elegant but it allows me to use a single report in the two scenarios of opening automatically for a specific date range, or opening at the users request with user specified dates.
I have amended the reports so their default record source uses Date() and Date()+14 for the report date range.
When the report is opened by a user from the "Report Selection" form, "User" is passed through via OpenArgs.  The OnOpen event of the form checks the value of OpenArgs and if it is set to "User", changes both the report's record source and the controls that display the report date range to use the dates entered by the user on the selection form.
@kostasK. thank you for all your input, you helped me get to this solution.